# Home became ä¸»é¡µ

Tags: php, joomla, percona

After I ran software upgrade "apt-get upgrade" on DB server, chinese characters become weird

Joomla 2.5.16

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 with fpm-fcgi/php5-fpm

nginx 1.4.6

mysqld (Percona XtraDB Cluster) 5.6.26-74.0

I had tried setting default charset to utf8 in php.ini, nothing change.

I also tried setting "character-set-server = utf8" & "collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci" in my.cnf of its DB server with same result.

Where else should I start looking?

Comment: Further observation: I prepared a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 with percona server then uploaded joomla folder and restored its database. Still same character issue as on production server.

Comment: restoring database to last known good database asolvd this.